# Filtering an array for only unique values

Tags: javascript, filter

for example if `arr = [1,1,2,3,5,5]` this will return `[1,2,3,5]`.

```
function returnUnique(arr) {
      
      let unique = [...new Set(arr)];
      return unique;
    };
```

my goal is to return only 2,3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function returnUnique(arr) {
  return arr.filter(e => arr.indexOf(e) === arr.lastIndexOf(e));
}

console.log( returnUnique([1,1,2,3,5,5]) );
```

Comment: he just want to convert an array to a set, which is a question answered several times

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia no he answered the question exactly as asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve the result using [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```js
const arr = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5];

const map = new Map();
arr.forEach((n) => map.set(n, (map.get(n) ?? 0) + 1));

const result = [];
for (let [k, v] of map) {
  if (v === 1) result.push(k);
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce` function, for example:

```js
const array = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6];

const uniqueValues = (array) => array.reduce((arr, item) => {
if (!arr.some((filteredItem) =>
        JSON.stringify(filteredItem) === JSON.stringify(item)
    ))
    arr.push(item);
return arr;
}, []);
console.log(uniqueValues(array))
```